# If NetService is deprecated, how should I do mDNS on macOS?

Tags: ios, macos, mdns

My applications have been pretty successful at using mDNS to advertise and discover services. However, I was looking up documentation and found that Apple has flagged their Bonjour classes as deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bonjour I've been searching, but I haven't found any indication of what I should use instead. What framework am I supposed to use to do mDNS if Apple drops NetService and NetServiceBrowser some time in the future?

Comment: It might be a documentation error. Actually using the class in Xcode beta doesn't give a deprecation warning

Comment: It's not warning me in Xcode, either, but I assumed that was because I was targeting an OS version where it wasn't yet deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've seen some post on the Apple developer forums mentioning this. They seem to be pushing folks towards Network Framework. It appears `nw_listener_set_advertise_descriptor` is the replacement. See:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/2976786-nw_listener_set_advertise_descri

Update: Managed to locate one of the threads on the developer forums. See: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682744

Comment: Wow, I completely missed this entire new framework. It would be nice if the documentation for the old stuff had a link to the new framework. Usually if a single method is deprecated there is text explaining what should be used instead.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the replacement [NWBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwbrowser) is only available since iOS 13.

Comment: How can i use this from C++ code?  Are they really starting to force our business logic to become Swift code now?

Comment: @Lothar this is available as a C funtcion as well, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/2976786-nw_listener_set_advertise_descri?language=objc

Answer (score -2):

You no need use Bonjour, you can realise mDNS or SSDP multicast request just using Darwin socket and realise mDNS or SSDP protocol by using necessary datagram as `IPPROTO_UDP` and send binary or text data (in SSDP case)